# inner product function without using array subscripting in C

Tags: c

I try to write a fuction for inner product, but program doesnt work properly.
Can you tel me where is my mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int inner_product(const int *a, const int *b, int size) 
{
  int sum = 0, i;

  for (i=0; i<size; ++i) 
  sum += *(a+i) * *(b+i);

   return sum; 
}


int main()
{
    int n, a, b;
    printf("How many elements do you want to store?  ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("%d",inner_product(&a,&b,n));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are used unnitialized.

Comment: And there is only *one* of each (`a` and `b`), making `*(a+i)` and the b-derivation invoke UB when `size > 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to start with :

**In main:**

```
int n, a, b; //   a & b are not initialized
.
scanf("%d",&n); // Think what is the use of n here.
.
printf("%d",inner_product(&a,&b,n)); 
/*  You passed address of a and b, this is OK but the value they
 *  store is indeterminate as per the standard
 */
```

**In the function**

```
 for (i=0; i<size; ++i) 
 sum += *(a+i) * *(b+i); // Accessing the memory out of bound for size>1 behavior is undefined
// Remember you have only two pointers which you can legally dereference ie a and b
```

Comment: How do i initialize them ?

Comment: Like `int a=5,b=6;` or use scanf to read their values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the pointers a, b should be initialised to make that piece of code working.
You introduce them as "int" values. So, these "arrays" have item count of 1, so you do not need any cycle to calculate the sum.

In addition to that, it is much better to not use complex constructions like

```
*(a+i)
```

It is better (and much more easy readable) to say:

```
a[i]
```

instead.

Also, there could potentially be a overflow problem in your code - what if there are two values entered (in a[i] and b[i]), which produce sum bigger than "int" type can contain (more than 2^32)?
You are calculating sum of two integers into third integer without any checks. In production software it could lead to a security flaw.

Comment: The question does specifically say "without using array subscripting", so it's not very productive to suggest using subscripting.

Comment: It is just a suggestion how to write more readable code.