# inner product function in C

Tags: c

I try to write a fuction for inner product without using array subscripting. I have been looking the code for hours.
Still I could not fix mistake. Can someone fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int inner_product(int *a, int *b, int size)
{
    int sum = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("enter value for first array: ");
        scanf("%d", &(a + i));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("enter value for first array: ");
        scanf("%d", &(b + i));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        sum += *(a + i) * *(b + i);

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int n, a, b;
    printf("How many elements do you want to store?  ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("%d", inner_product(&a, &b, n));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is...a lot wrong with this. It looks like you're trying to treat `int`s as `int` arrays?

Comment: How do you (or we) know that there is a mistake?

Comment: Your classmate asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058242/inner-product-function-without-using-array-subscripting-in-c) recently.

Comment: What do you think `&(a + i)` gives you a pointer to when `i` is not zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have so many errors in your code. First, you are not defining your arrays as arrays, but as single int values. You should define them correctly:

```
int *a, *b;
```

Second, you are not allocating your arrays. If you want to create them on runtime you will have to use `malloc()` after you get the size for them:

```
a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Third, it is not necessary to pass your array values as reference, because you will not need to modify them:

```
printf("%d", inner_product(a, b, n));
```

Inside your `inner_product()` function:

`&(a + i)` and `&(b + i)` won't give you the memory position of the array item (because it depends on the memory block size). You should use `&a[i]` and `&b[i]` instead to get the array values.

Because your variables `a` and `b` are arrays, your inner product should be calculated this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    sum += a[i] * b[i];
```

Tip: be sure to freeing your allocated `a` and `b` arrays by calling `free(a)` and `free(b)` after calling `inner_product()`.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

a and b must be arrays with memory allocated to them.

```
int a[1000];
int b[1000];
```

is a quick fix, but best if the code checks that inputs are no larger than 1000 (if this is only a class assignment, you can get away without such checks, but production code needs to be more robust).  You would not need & before `a` and `b` when calling the function, i.e. instead call `inner_product(a, b, n)`.